# How to form an array for query from URL with multiple parameters

Tags: php, sql, arrays, wordpress, url-parameters

This is on the second page of a filter that I am making, on the first page the user is able to select check-boxes. The values of the check-boxes get passed to the second page by parameters in the URL: 
`filter-result/?mytaxonomy=myterm&mytaxonomy=myotherterm`
How to form an array of this data to use in a (WP) query?

I'm able to display the data from the URL by doing this:

```
    if( isset( $_GET['mytaxonomy'] ) ){
        foreach( $_GET['mytaxonomy'] as $term ){
            echo $term . '<br>';
        }
    }
```

I am also able to query posts (custompost-type):

```
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'mycustomposttype',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'mytaxonomy',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array( 'myterm', 'myotherterm' ),
                'operator' => 'AND',
            ),
        ),
    ) );
```

I want to pass the data from `$_GET['mytaxonomy']` to `'terms' => array( *inside here* )`.

When I use `print_r ($_GET['mytaxonomy']);` the result is `Array ( [0] => myterm )`, All correct. I guess I just need to form the array to `'a', 'b'` to work in the WP query. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

For others that may question how to go about this: this was an easy fix. Because as @Wodka suggested, I formed the link with [] brackets like such: `<input type="checkbox" name="mytaxonomy[]" value="myterm">` and because `$_GET['mytaxonomy']` outputs an `array()` itself, I was able to just drop it in like below.

`'terms' => $_GET['mytaxonomy'],`

Which resulted in:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'mycustomposttype',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'mytaxonomy',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $_GET['mytaxonomy'],
            'operator' => 'AND',
        ),
    ),
) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass array to php like `filter-result/?mytaxonomy[]=myterm&mytaxonomy[]=myotherterm` - the syntax you used is from the java world (and not applicable to php)

Comment: That is actually how I did form the URL. On the first page, there is a form with: `<label><input type="checkbox" name="mytaxonomy[]" value="myterm">myterm</label>`.